# How to know length of the drop-down list using protractor webdriver?

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor

I am working on a task where I am automating the front end pages. There I need to get the length of the drop-down list but I haven't found any suggestions regarding the same in protractor type script.

My xpath is:

> //*[@id=intrestmethod'].

I am getting the drop-down value with below code but I need to know the total drop-down values present in it .

```
browser.driver.findelement(xpathvalue).getAttribute('value').then((function(attributevalue){
Console.log(attributevalue);
}):
```

Comment: Something like `ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('.my-dropdown-list-option')).length;` ?

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML for our list? Is it a `select` with many `option`'s?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count()` method on all available drop-down elements.

Remember that it returns a `promise.Promise<number>`.

See the documentation:

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
const listCount = browser.driver.findelements(xpathvalue).count(); // returns the count of list elements
```

Hope it helps you